# How do I sort my string list with Recursion?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to write code where it creates a string list increasing order with using only recursion and nothing else.

How should I go about doing this?

```
(define (create-list n st)
  (cond [(zero? n) ""]
        [else (string-append "X" (create-list (sub1 n)  st))]))

(define (stair n)
   (cond [(equal? n 0) empty]
              [else (cons (create-list n "x") (stair (- n 1)))]))

;; (stair 4) --> (list "XXXX" "XXX" "XX" "X")
```

Desired output: `(list  "X" "XX" "XXX" "XXXX")`

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
(cons (create-list n "x") (stair (- n 1)))
```

with

```
(append (stair (- n 1)) (list (create-list n "Q")))
```

(Note that `create-list` doesn't actually use the `st` argument.)

Comment: true. i missed that

Answer (score 1):

All Scheme lists are created from end to beginning. You want to create `("XXXX")` first, then `("XXX" "XXXX")` etc. Whenever you do `(cons "X" (recursion ....))` then `(recursion ...)` needs to finish before the `cons` while the most efficient is by using an accumulator. Using `append` each step smell wrong since `append` is O(n) so if you do do that each step then you have O(n^2). With a couple of thousand elements you'll start noticing the difference.

You don't need `create-list`, which doesn't create a list but a string, since Scheme has `make-string` that does what you want:

```
(make-string 3 #\X) ; ==> "XXX"
```

So here is stair:

```
(define (stair n)
  (define (xs n)
    (make-string n #\X))
  (let helper ((n n) (acc '()))
    (if (zero? n)
        acc
        (helper (- n 1) 
                (cons (xs n) acc)))))
```

So in this case if you wanted it in the reverse order you would have used different name than `n` and gone upward until this and `n` were passed. Sometimes you don't have the luxury to choose, eg, if you were to copy a list, then often you can building the reverse, then reverse the result. Sometime you need to use memory and need the continuations, but this will restrict how deep your structures can be before the program stops working. In rackets case it doesn't stop until you have depleted the whole heap memory you have supplied it.